# Custom view sizes for different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I have made a custom view by extend the `View` class.  Currently I have an `int` which defines the size of view.  Then I override the `onMeasure` method and made the width and height equal to the int.

Like this:

```
private int DEFAULT_SIZE = 80;
public Paint mOuterCirclePaint = new Paint();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

mOuterCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mOuterCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
    mOuterCirclePaint.setDither(true);
    mOuterCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    setMeasuredDimension(
            DEFAULT_SIZE + 5
                    + (int) mOuterCirclePaint.getStrokeWidth() / 2,
            DEFAULT_SIZE + 5
                    + (int) mOuterCirclePaint.getStrokeWidth() / 2);

}


public void setSize(int defaultSize) {
    DEFAULT_SIZE = defaultSize;
    invalidate();
```

}

But this means my view does not scale well on different devices of different resolutions.  On a high resolution device, the view appears small, but on a low resolution device, the view is large.

I don't think creating a new view for each resolution is a good idea.  I have tried scaling the view my multiplying the `DEFAULT_SIZE` by the density of the device (`float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`), but this doesn't have an affect on the low res device, but makes the view take up more than the whole screen (you can't see it) on the high res device

So what is the best way to make a custom view for different devices? Am I on the right lines or is there a another way of doing it?

Comment: I think `float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` is the correct approach. Make sure DEFAULT_SIZE it is the correct value for mdpi devices

Comment: @ramaral The size is correct for mdpi devices, but the same problem occurs when using it on xhdpi.  The view takes up more than the whole screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use dimension resources and use

```
int defaultSize = (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_size);
```

in constructor of custom view with this in *res/values/dimes.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_size">80dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Now the size will be scaled due to density of the screen of device.

Here is simple example of measured view:

```
public class MeasuredView extends View
{
    private int m_defaultSize;

    public MeasuredView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public MeasuredView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        setMeasuredDimension(m_defaultSize, m_defaultSize);
    }

    private void init(Context context)
    {
        m_defaultSize = (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_value);
    }
}
```

On xhdpi size is 160 px, on hdpi its 120 and on mdpi its 80.

You should know that `setSize(int defaultSize)` takes argument value as pixels so if you want to set it as dp you can write method

```
public void setDefaultSizeDp(int defaultSizeDp)
    {
        int defaultSizePx = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, defaultSizeDp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        m_defaultSize = defaultSizePx;
        invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: This would mean creating a different layout file for each device resolution.  Is this how it's "normally" done?

Comment: This is not creating any layout. Its just creating dimension resource and getting the resource value anywhere in application from Context and its Resources object.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference at all. The size is not being changed

Comment: What types of devices do you test? This getting values from resources depends on screen density and is scaled properly due to device density. If the devices you test have different screen size, but same density than the size is same.

Comment: I'm comparing a Nexus 4 (4.7" xhdpi, Android 4.4) with Motorola Xoom (10.1" mdpi, Android 4.2)

Comment: So Nexus 4 has 318 ppi so the wiew with size 80 dp will have size of 160 px that is approx 0.5 inch. On Xoom with 160 ppi the size is 80 px which leads to 0.5 inches again. That is why the size is same in real.

Comment: But the size of the view on the xoom is much bigger. Roughly twice the size.

Comment: I will make sample in an hour.

Comment: Thanks! I have used xml resources before, so I will check again to make sure I'm not missing something obvious

Comment: Updated my answer. I tried this and it is scaling correctly on different densities. You can test it with background color for example.